# Fitting a curve in gnuplot: Repeated fitting give different results

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have been trying to fit the equation y = Ax^2 + Bx + C to the following set of data (data.txt):

```
-9.39398e+09 1.52819e-19
-9.07008e+09 1.50337e-19
-8.74617e+09 1.44628e-19
-8.42227e+09 1.37837e-19
-8.09817e+09 1.31042e-19
-7.77427e+09 1.24624e-19
-7.45037e+09 1.18873e-19
-7.12646e+09 1.11213e-19
-6.80256e+09 1.00253e-19
-6.47865e+09 8.95713e-20
-6.15475e+09 7.92741e-20
-5.83066e+09 6.94736e-20
-5.50675e+09 6.02803e-20
-5.18285e+09 5.1667e-20
-4.85894e+09 4.37442e-20
-4.53504e+09 3.65056e-20
-4.21113e+09 3.00328e-20
-3.88723e+09 2.4281e-20
-3.56332e+09 1.93223e-20
-3.23923e+09 1.49467e-20
-2.91533e+09 1.13226e-20
-2.59142e+09 8.33933e-21
-2.26752e+09 5.93767e-21
-1.94361e+09 4.05992e-21
-1.61971e+09 2.64039e-21
-1.29581e+09 1.623e-21
-9.71713e+08 9.0523e-22
-6.47809e+08 4.05351e-22
-3.23904e+08 8.97219e-23
0 0
3.23904e+08 8.97219e-23
6.47809e+08 4.05351e-22
9.71713e+08 9.0523e-22
1.29581e+09 1.623e-21
1.61971e+09 2.64039e-21
1.94361e+09 4.05992e-21
2.26752e+09 5.93767e-21
2.59142e+09 8.33933e-21
2.91533e+09 1.13226e-20
3.23923e+09 1.49467e-20
3.56332e+09 1.93223e-20
3.88723e+09 2.4281e-20
4.21113e+09 3.00328e-20
4.53504e+09 3.65056e-20
4.85894e+09 4.37442e-20
5.18285e+09 5.1667e-20
5.50675e+09 6.02803e-20
5.83066e+09 6.94736e-20
6.15475e+09 7.92741e-20
6.47865e+09 8.95713e-20
6.80256e+09 1.00253e-19
7.12646e+09 1.11213e-19
7.45037e+09 1.18873e-19
7.77427e+09 1.24624e-19
8.09817e+09 1.31042e-19
8.42227e+09 1.37837e-19
8.74617e+09 1.44628e-19
9.07008e+09 1.50337e-19
9.39398e+09 1.52819e-19
```

In gnuplot I typed the command:

```
fit a*x**2 + b*x + c 'data.txt' via a, b, c
```

The result spit out is:

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = -1.73185e-20     +/- 2.658e-11    (1.535e+11%)
b               = 1                +/- 0.1325       (13.25%)
c               = 1                +/- 1.076e+09    (1.076e+11%)

correlation matrix of the fit parameters:
                a      b      c      
a               1.000 
b              -0.000  1.000 
c              -0.739  0.000  1.000
```

When I plot using the values of a, b, c there is no fit between the data and the fitted line.

So I again give the command

```
fit a*x**2 + b*x + c 'data.txt' via a, b, c
```

Then gnuplot spits out the following output:

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = -1.73185e-20     +/- 3.278e-21    (18.93%)
b               = -2.24969e-22     +/- 1.645e-11    (7.313e+12%)
c               = 1                +/- 0.1327       (13.27%)

correlation matrix of the fit parameters:
                a      b      c      
a               1.000 
b               0.000  1.000 
c              -0.739 -0.001  1.000
```

The values of a, b, c has changed but this also doesn't give satisfactory fit with the data.
So I once again give the command:

```
fit a*x**2 + b*x + c 'data.txt' via a, b, c
```

This time the following result is spit out:

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = 1.96019e-39      +/- 5.98e-33     (3.051e+08%)
b               = -2.24969e-22     +/- 2.98e-23     (13.25%)
c               = -1.11942e-21     +/- 2.421e-13    (2.162e+10%)

correlation matrix of the fit parameters:
                a      b      c      
a               1.000 
b               0.000  1.000 
c              -0.739 -0.000  1.000
```

This also did not give satisfactory fit.

Then again I repeat the fit command and get the following:

```
After 4 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 2.4063e-39
abs. change during last iteration : -2.64182e-48


Hmmmm.... Sum of squared residuals is zero. Can't compute errors.

Final set of parameters 
======================= 

a               = 1.96019e-39    
b               = 2.01689e-41    
c               = -1.11942e-21
```

Now the values of a, b, c give very good fitting with data.

My questions are:

1. Why did the values of a, b, c not give good fit with data on the first, second and third attempt?
2. Can I use the a, b, c values calculated in the end ?
3. In the output of the last attempt, should I worry about the message "Hmmmm.... Sum of squared residuals is zero. Can't compute errors." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your values have a too wide numerical range and I guess that some computations (like the residual for instance) are erroneous due to truncation error.

If you normalize your data by multiplying the first column by 10^-9 and the second one by 10^18

```
-9.39398 0.152819
-9.07008 0.150337
-8.74617 0.144628
-8.42227 0.137837
-8.09817 0.131042
-7.77427 0.124624
-7.45037 0.118873
-7.12646 0.111213
-6.80256 0.100253
-6.47865 0.0895713
-6.15475 0.0792741
-5.83066 0.0694736
-5.50675 0.0602803
-5.18285 0.051667
-4.85894 0.0437442
-4.53504 0.0365056
-4.21113 0.0300328
-3.88723 0.024281
-3.56332 0.0193223
-3.23923 0.0149467
-2.91533 0.0113226
-2.59142 0.00833933
-2.26752 0.00593767
-1.94361 0.00405992
-1.61971 0.00264039
-1.295810 0.001623
-0.971713 0.00090523
-0.647809 0.000405351
-0.323904 0.0000897219
0 0
0.323904 0.0000897219
0.647809 0.000405351
0.971713 0.00090523
1.295810 0.001623
1.61971 0.00264039
1.94361 0.00405992
2.26752 0.00593767
2.59142 0.00833933
2.91533 0.0113226
3.23923 0.0149467
3.56332 0.0193223
3.88723 0.024281
4.21113 0.0300328
4.53504 0.0365056
4.85894 0.0437442
5.18285 0.051667
5.50675 0.0602803
5.83066 0.0694736
6.15475 0.0792741
6.47865 0.0895713
6.80256 0.100253
7.12646 0.111213
7.45037 0.118873
7.77427 0.124624
8.09817 0.131042
8.42227 0.137837
8.74617 0.144628
9.07008 0.150337
9.39398 0.152819
```

Then

```
gnuplot> fit a*x**2 + b*x + c 'data.txt' via a, b, c
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   a             b             c            
   0 2.4049966612e-03   0.00e+00  4.62e-02    1.960970e-03   6.941376e-15  -1.162140e-03
   1 2.4049966612e-03  -1.79e-09  4.62e-03    1.960970e-03   6.941376e-15  -1.162140e-03
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   a             b             c            

After 1 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 0.002405
rel. change during last iteration : -1.78522e-14

degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 56
rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 0.00655335
variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 4.29464e-05

Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = 0.00196097       +/- 3.136e-05    (1.599%)
b               = 6.94138e-15      +/- 0.0001416    (2.04e+12%)
c               = -0.00116214      +/- 0.00128      (110.1%)

correlation matrix of the fit parameters:
                a      b      c      
a               1.000 
b               0.001  1.000 
c              -0.745 -0.001  1.000
```

is stable

---

If A,B,C are the fitted parameters from the normalized data, then you can get your initial a,b,c parameters (those corresponding to the raw data) by:

```
a = A / (10^18 * 10^18) = A * 10^-36
b = B / (10^9 * 10^18) = B * 10^-27
c = C / 10^18 = C * 10^-18
```

**Explanation/update2:**

Let (xi,yi), i=1,2,..n be your initial data, you want to fit:

```
y ≈ a x^2 + b x + c
```

However, for your computer it is better to work with:

```
Y ≈ A X^2 + B X + C
```

where X = 10^-9 x, Y = 10^18 y

To find a,b,c from A,B,c just proceed by identification:

```
Y ≈ A X^2 + B X + C => 10^18 y ≈ A 10^-18 x^2 + B 10^-9 x + C
                    =>       y ≈ A 10^-36 x^2 + B 10^-27 x + C 10^-18
      to be compared to      y ≈ a x^2        + b x        + c
```

by consequence you have:

```
a = A * 10^-36
b = B * 10^-27
c = C * 10^-18
```

Is it ok now?

Comment: Is there a way to get from the values of a, b, c for the normalized data, the values of a, b, c for the unnormalized data?

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for the formulas you mentioned in the update ?

Comment: It didn't work when I tried to multiply second column by 1E20